# Append to file in loop fails with file ENOENT error in Node.js

Tags: node.js, fs

I am trying to write into a file continuously. As the file can grow really larger, using fs.appendFile adding data to the file. Randomly it fails with error:

**Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/parentDir/html/56e6fd2XXX.html'**

I need to create the file with data of say 100000. So I am appending to the file one by one, that too in batches(as 100 per batch). After say 35000(random) it fails with error no such file or directory.

Couldn't understood where am I missing.

```
fs.appendFile(htmlPath, dataToWriteInHtml, function (err) {        
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            console.log(htmlPath);
            console.log(dataToWriteInHtml);
            callback(err);
        }
        else {                                             
            callback(null);
        }
    });
```

Comment: please add whole code

Comment: This **might** also be a bug in Node.js because according to docs, `appendFile` ["Asynchronously appends data to a file, **creating the file if it does not yet exist**"](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_appendfile_path_data_options_callback).

Comment: I suspect auto cleanup process. I think this post may explain reason of Your issue: https://askubuntu.com/questions/20783/how-is-the-tmp-directory-cleaned-up

Comment: @fardjad it's not nodejs issue. it may be race condition with other system process when resource may be busy or may be removed when nodejs tries to append after checking that it exists. So I would recommend to work with files with `fs.createWriteStream` to avoid such situations or do recursion that will create file if it does not exist when it will crash.

Comment: @num8er No its not cleanup I guess. Because file do exists in the folder. I checked after it throws error. Also I want write as html. Is it possible write as html and not as string?

Comment: @num8er Well, I don't know! Looking at the source-code [`fs.appendFile` calls writeFile with append flag set, which calls open, which in turn](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/d4c91f28148af8a6c1a95392e5c88cb93d4b61c6/lib/fs.js#L1264) [calls the open syscall](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html). According to the man page, "The open() system call opens the file specified by pathname. If the specified file does not exist, it may optionally (if O_CREAT is specified in flags) be created by open()". So it either doesn't pass `O_CREAT` (very unlikely) or something else is going on.

Comment: @fardjad I guess here the condition is different. The file is there and been written with say 40000 data already. Now its throwing error. If so file already exist right.So I couldn't get your point "If the specified file does not exist, it may optionally..."

Comment: @jerry My point is, that exception should never be thrown regardless of the race conditions or whether the file gets deleted in the middle of the process. But I'm not sure what's wrong.